# Can an intersection of the closure of opens have interior points, if the intersection of the opens is empty?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Hi everyone: Suppose $(V_{n})$ is a sequence of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ for $N\geq2$. If $\bigcap_{n}V_{n}=\emptyset$, can we conclude that the intersection of the closures $\bigcap_{n}\overline{V_{n}}$  has empty interior?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If $U$ is open and $U\subset \overline{V_n}$ then $U\subset V_n$. So, the answer is no.

Comment: since $\mu(U) = \mu(\overline{U})$  it can have only measure $0$ subsets

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp That's not exactly true.  Let $X=U=[0,1]$ and $V=(0,1)$. Then $U\subseteq \overline V$ but $U\not \subseteq V$.

Comment: @ForeverMozart We are talking about the topology of $\mathbb R^N$ here. So, your example is not valid.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp. If $V_n$ is open and dense in $R^n$ but $V_n\ne R^n$ and the open  set $U$  has a point not in $V_n$ , then $U\subset R^n=\bar V_n$ but $U\not \subset V_n.$....

Comment: Damn, you are right. I will delete my answer.

Comment: Not true. If $U\subset \overline{V_{n}}$ then $U\subset \overset{\circ}{\overline{V_{n}}}$, which is not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this follows from the Baire category theorem.  If $B\subseteq\bigcap \overline{V_n}$ is an open ball, let $W_n=V_n\cap B$.  Then each $W_n$ is a dense open subset of $B$, so by the Baire category theorem their intersection must be nonempty.  This is a contradiction.

Comment: You should make $B$ a closed ball because otherwise you cannot apply Baire.

Comment: You can apply Baire. An open subspace $B$ of a completely metrizable space is completely metrizable. If $B$ is a completely metrizable space and $F$ is a countable, non-empty family of dense open subsets of $B$ then $\cap F$ is dense in $B.$

Comment: Ah, ok... I did not know this generalization of Baire's original theorem. However, one can also apply the "usual" version here. Let $B$ be a closed ball and put $W_n := V_n\cap B$. Then $W_n$ is open dense in $B$.

Comment: I had in mind the version for locally compact Hausdorff spaces, actually.  But you can also use that $B$ is completely metrizable, or take a closed ball (note however that it takes slightly more effort to see that $W_n$ is dense in $B$ if you take a closed ball).